# center align all the p tags inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code, I want to center align all the p tags inside the div in all the media screen sizes. How do i do that?

```html
 <div id="thankyou_block">
        <p><br></p>
        <p><br></p>
        <div class="ticket_details">
            <p style="font-weight: 500;">Your concern !</p>
            <p class="case_num" style="font-weight: 500;">Please find the details: Ticket<span id="case_id"></span></p>
            <p>We will take time to review your concern and take necessary actions if needed</p>
        </div>

        <img id="thankyou_img"
            src="thankyou_opendoor.png">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-top: 30px;">
            <button id="back_to_portal" onclick="back_to_portal()">Back</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean just using ```text-align: center```?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to add this code `p {text-align: center}`

To be more specific and apply to this piece of code you can either give some class to every `<p>` element and write this code `{text-align: center}` to that class only .

Else you can add `thankyou_block` id before `p {text-align: center}` like this `#thankyou_block p {text-align: center}` to constraint it to `id="thankyou_block"` only

```css
p {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="thankyou_block">
  <p><br></p>
  <p><br></p>
  <div class="ticket_details">
    <p style="font-weight: 500;">Your concern !</p>
    <p class="case_num" style="font-weight: 500;">Please find the details: Ticket<span id="case_id"></span></p>
    <p>We will take time to review your concern and take necessary actions if needed</p>
  </div>

  <img id="thankyou_img" src="thankyou_opendoor.png">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-top: 30px;">
    <button id="back_to_portal" onclick="back_to_portal()">Back</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-align:center` to `#thankyou_block`:

```css
#thankyou_block{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="thankyou_block">
        <p><br></p>
        <p><br></p>
        <div class="ticket_details">
            <p style="font-weight: 500;">Your concern !</p>
            <p class="case_num" style="font-weight: 500;">Please find the details: Ticket<span id="case_id"></span></p>
            <p>We will take time to review your concern and take necessary actions if needed</p>
        </div>

        <img id="thankyou_img"
            src="thankyou_opendoor.png">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-top: 30px;">
            <button id="back_to_portal" onclick="back_to_portal()">Back</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```